# iPhone app with incrementing calling of text file, working with NSDate and NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsdate, nsuserdefaults

I am currently coding an app which calls a text file from a store, displays it and then increments so that the next file can be loaded when needed. I have got the base code to work by the use of a button click however I want it to be able to call the text file only when 24 hours has past since the last one was loaded effectively making it update every day.

I am trying to do this by using `NSDate` and NSUserDefaults to store the previous time that a file was called and then compare it to the current time, if it has been more than 24 hours increment and call the next.

However after trying to add things and change around the base code below I just cannot work out how to get it to work. I don't know if this is just because I have not had enough experience and don't know the language well enough or if I am just being a bit silly and missing something really simple.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
NSDate *nowDate = [NSDate date];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nowDate forKey:@"LastLoaded"];

NSDate *lastLoaded  = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"LastLoaded"];

NSDate *checkDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-24*60*60];
if([lastLoaded compare:checkDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    static int number = 1;
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",number++] ofType:@"txt"];
    if (filePath) {
        NSString *textFromFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        if (textFromFile) {
            textView.text = textFromFile;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: It displays the first text file, but after changing the date to 24 hours later it still shows the first one and doesn't update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in your code. You are not retrieving the last update date from NSUserDefaults. You are retrieving the current date, as you are overwriting the LastUpdatedate with current date in the very second line of code.

```
//NSDate *nowDate = [NSDate date];
//[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nowDate forKey:@"LastLoaded"];

NSDate *lastLoaded  = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"LastLoaded"];

//NSDate *checkDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-24*60*60];
if ([lastLoaded timeIntervalSinceNow] < -24*60*60 ){
//Now you can update the NSUserDefaults
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"LastLoaded"];
//if([lastLoaded compare:checkDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
static int number = 1;
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",number++] ofType:@"txt"];
if (filePath) {
    NSString *textFromFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    if (textFromFile) {
        textView.text = textFromFile;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, just displays the first text file and doesn't update. Could this be because each time the condition is true it sets number back to 1 overwriting the increment.

Comment: Can you try debugging a bit? like say put a Nslog for number and see its value inside the condition? is the condition being fired right by putting a nslog inside?

Comment: Added an NSLog onto number and it stays as 1 throughout changing the system date to the next day.

Comment: You got your additional bug. My advice store that number in NSUserDefaults and retrieve it from there as well. Makes sense?

Comment: Yes that does make sense, but would probably make more sense if I knew more about NSUserDefaults and how to store and recall integers from there.

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"number_key"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setinteger:number forKey:@"number_key"];..please accept the answer if your question is addressed.